# why is this not giving an output and the kernel is going on running as if it has gone under some loop?

Tags: python, linked-list

learning how to make linked lists?
pls provide with better solution if possible.
added push ,insertafter ,printlist,append functions.
learning how to make linked lists?
pls provide with better solution if possible.
added push ,insertafter ,printlist,append functions.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None 

    def push(self,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node
    def insertAfter(self,prev_node,new_data):
        if prev_node is None:
            print('Enter valid previous node data')
            return
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = prev_node.next
        prev_node.next = new_data

    def append(self,new_data):
        new_node= Node(new_data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
        last = self.head
        #while last.next!= None:
            #temp = last.next
            #last =temp.next
        while last.next:
            last = last.next
        last.next = new_node

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp:
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next

if __name__ =='__main__':
    llist = LinkedList()
    llist.append(7)
    llist.append(8)
    llist.push(5)
    llist.insertAfter(Node(5),6)
    llist.printList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix:

```
def append(self,new_data):
    new_node= Node(new_data)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new_node
        return  # <- this is the fix
    ...
```

Without this return statement, you go to this newly added node and assign its `.next` to itself. With this circular reference, the next `.append()` gets into infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `append` method. When you append the first node, `self.head` is None, so you execute:

`self.head = new_node`

But then you continue trying to find the `last` node, which in this case will also end up being `self.head`:

```
        last = self.head
        #while last.next!= None:
            #temp = last.next
            #last =temp.next
        while last.next:
            last = last.next
```

As a result, when you execute this line:

`last.next = new_node`

You are effectively setting `new_node.next = new_node`, which causes the next call to `append` to go into an infinite loop.